# Taking in a 2D vector of a string from a user but ends up getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, string, vector, cin, 2d-vector

I am trying to input a 2d vector of string "t" times and make a grid of 2 * 2 size "t" times using C++ and the inputs can be integers 0 to 8 (inclusive) and ".", so i tried using a 2d vector of string but I am getting segmentation fault when accessing any element of a row > 0. I think it's because cin is buffered. Can anyone guide to how to debug this or use any other method.

here's the code inside main

```
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        vector<vector<string> > grid(2);
        vector<string> temp(2);
        // vector<vector<char> > grid(2);
        // vector<char> temp(2);
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                cout<<j<<" "; //loop is running when *enter* is pressed
                cin>>temp[j];
    
                // cin.get(temp[j]);
            }
            grid[i] = temp;
            temp.clear();
        }
        cout<<"t-> "<<t<<" "<< grid[1][0]<<endl;  //getting segmentation fault here
    }
```

edit: if I put the `vector<string> temp(2)` inside first loop then it's working but idk why coz i did use clear() so idk why is this the case.

Comment: *How to debug this*. Use your debugger, learning how to use a debugger is the most important skill you will ever learn as a programmer. This is not an exaggeration.

Comment: Inside the loop makes a new vector with 2 elements each time round.

Comment: could u suggest some resources pls @john

Comment: @Harshil What compiler are you using? Every compiler uses a different debugger.

Comment: I use sublime text as my editor and default mac terminal to compile and run. Sometimes I use lldb to see the memory leaks but I don't know how use it properly like putting breakpoints and stuff.

Comment: @quazimo OK, that's an environment I'm very unfamiliar with. I could point you are any number of tutorials for lldb but I don't know if they are any good and you can google as well as me. However setting breakpoints and examining variables as you control the execution of your program is exactly what I am talking about. I also don't know anything about sublime text, but (personal opinion) I do think it's quite important to have a GUI to interact with your debugger. Debugging from the command line is rather cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing to do with `cin` being buffered.

The error is here

```
        temp.clear();
```

That line changes the size of `temp` to be zero, so on the next input `cin >> temp[j];` you have a vector subscript error because `temp` has zero size.

Just remove the line `temp.clear();` and your code will work.